Incorporating site-level random-effects and 2-dimensional spline of coordinates in a GAM in R
When building a Generalized Additive Model model using gam() from the mgcv package in R, one of the options within the spline term s() is the bs= argument. Descriptions of the options are given here, but in short, there are numerous options for smoothing which can be used to generate splines based geographic coordinates. There is also one option, bs = "re" to incorporate random-effects.
I am dealing with a situation where I have repeated site visits at sampling sites at varying locations. My goal is to both incorporate the random-effects of the repeated sampling, while also incorporating the spline of the two coordinate values at each site.
The model call looks something like:
gam(formula = DV ~ IV + s(lat,lon) + s(site,bs  = "re"),
    data = df)

What are the methods for incorporating random-effects in this way, and are two separate terms even necessary here? I.e., can I just model it in the following way?
gam(formula = DV ~ IV + s(lat,lon,bs = "re"),
    data = df)

or something similar, given the latitude and longitude pairs are unique and exactly equal to the categorical sites?

You want something like your first model. The spatial smooth will likely account for a lot of the site-to-site variation, but the random effect will mop up any residual site-to-site variation. It may be that you can't fit both a spatial smooth and the site random effect, but you'll only know that when you fit the model.
The second model is wrong; as there is no factor term, I think the smooth in that model will just end up being s(lat, lon).
Note that you probably want s(lon, lat) as lon is the x coordinate and lat is the y coordinate.

Great, glad to know I was thinking about it correctly. Lucky for me it manages to fit the model.
